# Angular AoT build import local json file

Tags: json, angular, import, build, aot

In my first angular app I have a service who import a json file to load some data (I need to load it synchronously, before the DOM).

In develop mode, when I modify the json file, the cli rebuild the app and all work like a charm.
Unluckily on *build -prod* modifying the json in my 'dist/assets' directory does not update the app. The compiler embed json into my `main-es2015.js` and do not reference anymore on external file.

**works.service.ts**:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import PICTURES  from '../../assets/pictures.json';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WorksService {
    pictures: any;

    constructor() {
      this.pictures = PICTURES
    }

    getWorks() { return this.pictures; }

    getSingleWork(id: string) { 

      return  this.pictures.find(i => i.id === id);}

    getPreviousWork(id: string) { 

      const index = this.pictures.findIndex(i => i.id === id) - 1;

      if (typeof this.pictures[index] === 'undefined') {
        // cycle to start
        return this.pictures[this.pictures.length-1]
      }
      else {
        return this.pictures[index]
      }
    }

    getNextWork(id: string) { 

      const index = this.pictures.findIndex(i => i.id === id) + 1;

      if (typeof this.pictures[index] === 'undefined') {
        // cycle to start
        return this.pictures[0]
      }
      else {
        return this.pictures[index]
      }
    }
}
```

I tried to use httpClient or to load the json dynamically:

```js
this.pictures = import('../../assets/pictures.json')
```

but the page is loaded before the file and I cant figure out how to load it before.

Comment: just add it  `angular.json`  so that it just copy's the file

Comment: @JoelJoseph what should I add to `angular.json`? I am a super new to the framework!

Comment: or you can just add this json file to `assets` folder which will copy the file as it is and  you can always access this file

Comment: @JoelJoseph the json is in the assets folder but somehow nothing happens when i modify it.

Comment: If you are still trying, here is more ideas for you to try. Load the JSON using httpClient in your constructor. But after loading, trigger a "loaded" subject event (rxjs's)  In your ui code, wait by subscribing to the worksService event.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to create a new `pictures.ts` file and put it into this file your JSON as an object.

```
// pictures.ts
export const pictures: any = { "name":"John", "age":30, "car":null };
```

after that import this const and use it into your components.

```
// pictures.component.ts
import { pictures } from "./pictures";
```

Comment: or you can just add this json file to `assets` folder which will copy the file as it is and  you can always access this file

Comment: Json file is alreay on assets folder, work on dev mode, doesnt update on production

Comment: @TarasKovalenko I tried to use your solution but still all data are embedded on `main-es2015.js` and do not reference on external json file.

Comment: @MarcoPiunti tries to use HttpClient to load this file. https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: @MarcoPiunti btw: did you tried to use `--base-href /` like `ng build --prod --base-href /`. I think this should help you.

Comment: @TarasKovalenko `--base-href /` does nothing (isn't it implicit?). I give up, Ill switch to HttpClient as you suggested